# ddev: run browsersync inside the container

Tags: ddev

This is basically the same question as [Docker and BrowserSync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819999/docker-and-browsersync) :

How can I access browsersync's port 3000 from the browser i.e. outside the docker container?

Why I post it separately: probably ddev provides some routing option to map the ports, so I don't have to change browsersync's options?

Comment: There are quite a number of examples in https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/additional-services/ and https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/tree/master/docker-compose-services - many of them expose ports either on the host directly or by using the VIRTUAL_HOST environment variable. Take a look there. I think you're going to end up being the expert on browsersync, so please remember to document your approach carefully!

Comment: I could use an answer here also.  @Urs, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, decided not to need browsersync